# Set navbar logo to the left

Tags: html, css

Hello everyone I make some navbar just for practice, and what I want is to set the logo straight to the left but I does not know how to do that. Also navbar should be responsive. 
Here is the code:

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  font-size: 10px;
}


/* Global */

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Header **/

header {
  background: #28292b;
  color: #ffffff;
  min-height: 50px;
}

header a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
}

header li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

header #branding {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

header #branding h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

header nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

header .highlight,
header .current a {
  color: #e8491d;
  font-weight: bold;
}

header a:hover {
  color: #cccccc;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="branding">
      <h1>LOGO</h1>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">ONE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">TWO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">THREE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FOUR</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FIVE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

When I resize to mobile phone width hamburger icon will appear and logo should be no more floated on the left. It should be on center.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe add a plunkr to get more help?

Comment: have a look into media queries, but there doesn't seem to be any attempt at this yourself, therefore I vote to close as too broad

Comment: You should at least make an attempt to achieve what you want to happen. No one is going to just wrote the code for you.

Comment: I have to use media queries for mobile size but logo should be on the left on full size screen, for exemple like on tesla web site

Comment: your logo is on the left - if you want it further to the left then increase the width of the container - it's only 80% at the moment which is why there is left spacing before the logo - make it 100% if you don't want any space

Comment: Thank You Pete, i already fixed it with giving it position absolute and some left padding but it was because of width of container class, thanks again, and have a good day all.